# Mixin modules into models in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to have functionality shared by several models to be abstracted into a module.

I have this model:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AppModel
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tag
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :user
end
```

(also, how do I make my code span multiple lines on stackoverflow? it doesn`t preserve my newlines.)

Then I have a module (in app/models/app_model.rb):

```
module AppModel 
  def self.list
    find(:all, :order => 'name asc').map { |item| [item.name, item.id] }
   end
end
```

but if I do `Report.list` it doesn't work. I suspect there's a problem if in a module I do `def function` or `def self.function`?

So again my question is, how do I make accessible a function such as `Report.list` or `Report.find_tagged` that is defined in a module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**include** mix the instances methods, not class-level. Use **extend** method or orverride **include**.

P.S. to use code-formatting on SO use *{}*

Comment: you can read [the article](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) by John Nunemaker